# ContentType header with json schema URL parameter in Spring WebClient

Tags: java, spring, http-headers, spring-webclient

I'm using Spring to integrate towards a third party API. This API validates the Content-Type header and requires it to be exactly
`application/json;profile=https://se.digitalreceipts.net/schemas/json/retail/v1.0`

The code below is the relevant part of the POST call i make towards the API.

```
    webClient.post()
        .uri("/dr/v1/receipts")
        .attributes(clientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json;profile=https://se.digitalreceipts.net/schemas/json/retail/v1.0")
```

When executing this request an exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "application/json;profile=https://se.digitalreceipts.net/schemas/json/retail/v1.0": Invalid token character ':' in token "https://se.digitalreceipts.net/schemas/json/retail/v1.0"
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:620) ~[spring-web-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
```

Seems that spring does not allow colons in the Content-Type header.
This is an issue as the API I'm integrating towards absolutely requires the content-type header to be exactly as previously specificated.
I can't for instance write the value with quotation marks
`application/json;profile="https://se.digitalreceipts.net/schemas/json/retail/v1.0"`

I'm looking for a solution where I can enter the required Content-Type header using Spring WebClient.

Answer (score 1):

The `Content-Type` header must follow the format described on [RFC 2045 section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1). It is stated that special characters must be in quoted-string, to use within parameter values.

Spring parses the `Content-Type` header before executing the REST API call and [validates](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/MimeTypeUtils.java#L201) the mimeType.
If we quote the value of `profile` attribute then the mimeType is valid.
For example:

```
webClient.post()
    .uri("/dr/v1/receipts")
    .attributes(clientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId))
    .header("Content-Type", "application/json;profile=\"https://se.digitalreceipts.net/schemas/json/retail/v1.0\"")
```